# How do delete a jar file within an aar file?

Tags: android, gradle, jar, aar

So I'm trying to get an app to run at work but i get this error:

> Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK org/snmp4j/util/doc-files/org_snmp4j_util.gif
>       File1: /Users/Kelson/Documents/AndroidStudioProjects/aspen-android/app/libs/snmp4j.jar
>       File2: /Users/Kelson/Documents/AndroidStudioProjects/aspen-android/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/libscanmanager-release/jars/libs/snmp4j.jar
>       File3: /Users/Kelson/Documents/AndroidStudioProjects/aspen-android/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/devicediscoverymanager-release/jars/libs/snmp4j.jar

I think it's throwing this error because snmp4j.jar is already in the app libs folder, but then in the libscanmanager and devicediscoverymanager aar files snmp4j is also included and being compiled again. I think the solution is to delete snmp4j from the aar files but I can't figure out how to do it. Every time I try snmp4j gets rebuilt inside the aar. This is what the files look like in the external libraries tab. 
[link to pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nzac.png)

What I think is happening is that each time its run it recompiles snmp4j.jar from org.snmp4j inside classes.jar, so each time I try to delete snmp4j.jar it just gets recreated. Manually deleting org.snmp4j doesn't seem to work. So is there a way to delete it or stop it from compiling? Or would I have to go to the source of libscanmanager and devicediscoverymanager and rebuild the library before using them in the main app?

Or is this completely the wrong approach and I'm missing something really obvious?

**UPDATE**

So I think I found a possible track to a solution which is to add an exclude command like so

```
compile(name: 'devicediscoverymanager-release', ext: 'aar') {
    exclude module: 'snmp4j'
}
```

but I'm not too sure of the exact syntax so that hasn't worked either. I've tried exclude module, exclude group with snmp4j.jar, snmp4j, org.snmp4j, etc. The problem might be that this is for dependencies and as far as I can tell snmp4j isn't a dependency for the libraries, its just being built. Is there a way to specifically exclude jars from being packaged into the apk with the jars coming from the app's external libraries?

**Update 2**

So according to these guys: 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/g1AiJM7PeVs
its not actually possible for me to exclude the snmp4j from within the aar file. It seems that the library needs to be rebuilt to not include snmp4j

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same problem so in build.gradle file of your application
        in android section just add this block of code it does trick for me

```
 packagingOptions {
        exclude 'give file name which for which error is occuring'

    }
    for example-

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'

    }
```

Comment: I tried adding exclude 'snmp4j.jar' and exclude 'snmp4j' but those didn't work unless I have the syntax wrong.

Comment: @giant_raisens please make sure you have correct syntax and try it exclude 'path of that file in jar '